# How to specify Haddock options (pragmas) at the project level?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

From the [Haddock section](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#haddock) on Stephen Diehl's "What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell" page:

> haddock options can also be specified with pragmas in the source, either at the module or project level.

An example of a pragma at the module level is given:

> `{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK show-extensions, ignore-exports #-}`

but in which section of which file (when using `stack`) can these options be placed so as to apply to an entire project (or rather, "package")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/926

It seems that there is no way to put this in the `.cabal` file yet. I couldn't find any reference to haddock in the stack documentation. So the next best thing is to run `stack haddock --haddock-arguments "..."`.